# signalR/hubs doesn't contain the hub methods

Tags: signalr

I am using signalR 1.0.0 rc2 and have the code as following:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs; 

[HubName("chat")]
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public Chat()
    { 
    }
    [HubMethodName("send")]
    public void Send(string message,string  connectionId)
    {
        Clients.All(message);
    }
}
```

and i have the client side js :

```
$(function () {
    var myHub= $.connection.chat;
}
```

here i get the chat undefined.
i looked at the signalr/hubs and found

```
$.extend(signalR, {
   //here should have extended hub methods but has nothing   
});
```

what is the problem here is the hub not being initilized .I haven't included 
 `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()` in `global.asax.cs` (is it necessary to include this line?) . also when i include this line i get an error :

> Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.DependencyResolverExtensions.InitializePerformanceCoun>ters(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver, System.String,System.Threading.CancellationToken)'.

thanks .

Comment: I have gone through many releated questions but were of no help .and also read the signalr wiki and other documents but couldn't figure out .

Comment: You have an assembly mismatch. Delete everything related to signalr in your project and reinstall.

Comment: @Dfowler Do i have to include RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(). thanks for the quick response

Comment: I cleaned all the assemblies and added reference from nuget (microsoft.signalr.core & microsoft.signalr.hosting.aspnet). now i get the error : error loading hubs ensure your hub reference is correct . but when i add the dll signalR.Hosting.Aspnet.dll the hub is created but doesn't contain the hub methods(if i already have Microsoft.signalr.hosting.aspnet should i have to include SignalR.hosting.aspnet) .    please help ..thanks

Comment: Did you uninstall all packages and delete all references from the bin folder? Get everything CLEAN and then reinstall the packages using nuget?

Comment: I opened a new project and installed the package from the nuget. but the problem still persists. signalr/hubs is not generated .

Comment: Let's move this to the forum http://forums.asp.net/1254.aspx